# How can I create an object that fits in the gap of another object?

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

1. I decided I wanted slots in the checkpoints for a number plate to
   slide through and it to hold. It is a checkpoint for a mini drone
   race I am doing. I[image] basically want the "T" looking piece to be a gap
   in the circle and I will need to create a plate that will fit in the
   gap. Can anyone help me figure out how to join the 2 rectangles and
   make them a gap inside the circle.

   Also, someone mentioned the print would be too small. I could scale
   it in simplify 3d, but is there a way to scale it using blender?
   Also, Is there any way to measure the gap so the sliding in pieces
   fit tight? I downloaded the plug-in "Measure it" but am having
   issues figuring it out. It's a lot to take in, but with some
   previous help I am learning a lot and hopefully one day be able to
   help someone else out with a problem! Thanks

Comment: Please ask separate questions for separate problems as it'll be much easier for you and anyone facing similar problem to get help and for others to answer. As to "T looking piece" use [**Boolean** modifier](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html). Separate that T profile in another object, add modifier to your main one, select T profile as a cutter and choose *Difference*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of cutting actually doesn't require doing a boolean. You can use Knife Project instead.

First, using your T-shaped piece as a starting point, model a flat piece that is the same shape when viewed from the side. You can snap to verts while constraining the axes to do this.

[image: Modeled the cutter piece, and separating it into a new object]

Then, separate this into its own object. This object will cut into your circular one, so first select the cutter object and then Shift-select the circular one that will be cut (order of selection matters).

[image: Order of selection is important]

Tab into Edit Mode and Hide the parts of the mesh you won't be cutting (the T-shaped piece).

[image: T-piece hidden]

Select All, view from the side, and click Knife Project. Enable the Cut Through option in the Operator Panel.

[image: Viewed from the side]

[image: Knife Project button]

[image: Cut Through enabled]

You will end up with a nice clean cut in your mesh.

[image: The resulting cut]

You can then delete these faces and fill them in however you like.

[image: Faces filled]

Comment: How did you hide the T-Shaped piece?

Comment: @LarryGuthrie Oh, since it was a separate object I just moved it to an unused layer.